# Aerospike spikify - insert query to reset bin values to 0 not happening intermittently but timestamp field getting updated with same query

Tags: java, spring-boot, aerospike

We have around 32 bins in this aerospike set. Not sure if that is too much. After doing roughly around 9 or 10 odd insert queries via application to set 10 bin values to 0, along with changing a datetime field `lastUpdated`, this scenario has been observed wherein the numeric fields are not reset but the `lastUpdated` gets updated.

Here is class DetailsSet.class (Model for the set)

```
@SetName("details_set")
public class PrepaidAccountDetails {


@UserKey
@BinName("owner")
protected String owner;

@BinName("bin")
protected Double setBin;

..
32 bins


@BinName("lastUpdated")
protected Date lastUpdated;

//getters and setters
}
```

We tried adding some retry logic in the application code, if the numeric fields are not found 0 right after this query. However that failed as well.

Here is the application code using spikify library -

```
boolean valuesReset = false;
try {
    DetailsSet DetailsSet = sfy.transact(3, new Work<DetailsSet>() {
        public DetailsSet run() {
            Key key = new Key(asconf.getNamespace(), "details_set", account.owner());
            DetailsSet pa = sfy.get(DetailsSet.class).key(key).now();
            logger.info("resetting values");
            if (pa != null) {
                pa.setBin(BigDecimal.ZERO.doubleValue());
                //setting 10 other bins to zero similarly

                // reset counts
                pa.setLastUpdated(new Date());
                sfy.update(key, pa).now();
                logger.info("reset done successfully");
            }
            return pa;
        }
    });
    if (DetailsSet != null) {
        valuesReset = true;
    }

    Key key = new Key(asconf.getNamespace(), "details_set", account.owner());

    DetailsSet pa = sfy.get(DetailsSet.class).key(key).now();

    logger.info("checking if values have been reset");
    logger.info(
            "limits set to value  : {}",
            new Object[] { pa.getBin() });
    if (pa.getBin() != 0) {
        //this prints out
        logger.error("Values for owner {} has not been reset, so retrying !", new Object[] { account.owner() });
        valuesReset = false;
    }
    return valuesReset;
} catch (AerospikeException ae) {
    //exception is not thrown
    logger.error("Error while resetting values for owner {}",
            new Object[] { account.owner() }, ae);
    return false;
}
```

The output shows -

```
reset done successfully
limits set to value  : <Old Non zero value>
Values for owner <owner> has not been reset, so retrying !
```

Is there any such known issue with aerospike/spikify under some scenario?

Comment: trust the bin names for 32 bins are unique?  not clear from your code snippet.

Comment: Yes all the bin names are unique. Even if they were not unique, i.e. if I was trying updating same bin multiple times in a single query, shouldn't they be getting updated still?